# Setting up Serverless VPC Access on App Engine with variable project name

Tags: google-app-engine, google-vpc

I have an App Engine app that's attempting to connect to Redis Memcache via a serverless VPC connector. In my `app.yaml` for my service, I have setup the VPC Access connector block as

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: 'projects/<project_name>/locations/<region>/connectors/<connector>'
```

with the appropriate variables filled in. This works fine for the particular project I'm currently deploying to which is our testing project, but soon I'll need to deploy this to a different project with a different region and a different connector. Is there a way to setup this connection at runtime (when I have access python side to environment variables) rather than in the `app.yaml` file, or a way to pass environment variables to the `name` value in the yaml here?

Answer (score 1):

I verified this inquiry in the [Github for the python client library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard) but I did not found any way to achieve this. It seems that the only available option is adding the variable in the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements)

On the other hand, I would like to let you know that that I raised this [Public Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/176230545) requesting this since App engine can use the Admin API to update certain elements from the app.yaml file like a**utomaticScaling.min_idle_instances , manualScaling.instances and automaticScaling.max_total_instances**, so I consider a good idea  have a similar method to update the vpc_access_connector. I recommend you that you start the **PIT** in order to receive all the notifications